# Ionic2 Sqlite db file location

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, angular, cordova-plugins, ionic2

I know, that this question has many answers out there in the world of Google, but either I'm not so smart, or do something wrong) While developing with Ionic v1 I was been able to store by db file and access it from the app. But in Ionic 2 I'he tried many places where the file could be placed and nothing was working.
Here is the code that I use to connect db in my app:

```
return this._platform.ready().then(() => {
  this._storage = new Storage(SqlStorage, {
    name: 'dbname.db',
    backupFlag: SqlStorage.BACKUP_LOCAL,
    iosDatabaseLocation: 'default',
    existingDatabase: true
  });
});
```

but every time I have

> code: 5
>   message: "no such table: user"

Comment: I have the same issue, the doc is very poor

Comment: Did you guys manage to resolve your problem? Having the same issue :(

Comment: Same problem still. Any of you got it working by any chance?